# Get value from query before insert and use it after insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, plsql, pgadmin

I am trying to do a PostgreSQL function trigger that insert some values in one table after insert a record in other table of my database. this insert statement will be executed only if a certain condition is fulfilled.

The condition needs to compare one field value of the latest record in the table with the same field value of the current insertion. My problem is that, I don't know how to get the latest row inserted because when fire **on after insert trigger**" my current insertion is now my latest row. so the condition always will be `true`

This is my current approach:

```
DECLARE
    latest_val numeric;
    val_qry text := 'SELECT field_value FROM tablename WHERE type = ''$1'' order by date_field desc limit 1';

    sql text := 'INSERT INTO other_table( type, description)
                 SELECT $1, ''Data event was created'' WHERE $2 != $3';
BEGIN  
    EXECUTE val_qry INTO latest_val USING NEW.type; 
    EXECUTE sql USING NEW.type, latest_val, NEW.field_value;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

How can I get the field value of latest row before the new insert and then use it on after current insert? or another approach to do this?

Comment: is a reason [OFFSET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html) not work in your case ?